# RabbitMQ for work queue using consumers with different capabilities

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm creating a work queue setup where the different workers/consumers have different capabilities. By that I mean that not all work items can be run by all workers.

Let's say I have the following workers:

```
Worker A
    Capability 1
    Capability 2
    Capability 3
Worker B
    Capability 1
Worker C
    Capability 1
    Capability 3
```

- If a job requires `Capability 1`, it can be run by any worker.
- If a job requires `Capability 1` and `Capability 2`, it can only be run by `Worker A`.
- If a job requires `Capability 1` and `Capability 3` it can be run by `Worker A` or `Worker C`
- and so on...

**Question**

Is RabbitMQ capable/suitable for dispatching jobs for such a setup?

Answer (score 0):

```
Is RabbitMQ capable/suitable for dispatching jobs for such a setup?
```

Rabbit MQ is *very* flexible in terms of routing messages along with so many other nicer features it comes with. It is definitely capable of doing what you are hoping to do. Is it suitable is a much harder question to answer because it depends on so many other factors.

Here is one way to set up what you are trying to do

1. Create a **Direct Exchange** (Let us call it JobExchange).
2. Create **3 Queues** (JobType1.queue, JobType2.queue & JobType3.queue)
3. Brind all 3 Queues to your Exchange
4. Have **Worker A** listen to **JobType1.queue, JobType2.queue & JobType3.queue**
5. Have **Worker B** listen to **JobType1.queue**
6. Have **Worket C** listen to **JobType1.queue & JobType3.queue**

Note: IF there are multiple consumers which have the capability to process a certain Job (Example: Workers A,B & C can process JobType1), there is no way to control who picks up a message from the queue (JobType1.queue in this case). So one of the 3 workers will pick up the message and the other two will not get it.

Comment: Thank you. One thing, however, a job may have more than one requirement. Does that mean that I have to create queues for every combination of requirements as well? That's not an option for me I'm afraid because the number of individual conditions are > 20, hence all combinations will be a very large number of queues...

Comment: In that case, a more sophisticated exchange will be needed. Something like a Topic / Headers Ex is a good fit. With the Topic EX you will have to get creative with the Routing Key hierarchy and see if you can filter messages to fit your needs. If there is no real message hierarchy, then use a headers exchange where you can set multiple headers and tell rabbit to match ANY / ALL depending on what you need. As a side note, IF you cannot achieve filtering at the first level, you may have to create a hierarchy of exchanges and split them somewhere downstream. Hint: Ex -> Ex binding is allowed.